# How to move vertices closer together without actually scaling them

Tags: mesh, transforms, scale

Animation of what i mean with that title

[image]

https://youtu.be/akbRkCu_t4o

I tried the origins only but that didnt work at all.

Please only 2.8 solutions so that it becomes easier to everyone to understand it.

Comment: Is there another link? The one you posted goes to a private Facebook group.

Comment: Changed the link try it now.

Comment: "Origins only" is only in Object and Pose mode. You can down scale with Median Point with an exact number (for example s 0.5) then upscale with Individual Origins with the reciprocal (s 2). Of course not in vert selection mode, because in this case this is one island.

Comment: Consider a "push/pull" operation to median.

Comment: What ? I dont get what you two said...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to move the selection of vertices in opposite directions on the X axis without deforming the scale, right? If so, do it like this ...

---

1. In Edit Mode, select the vertices.

[image]

2. In the Sidebar, select the Push / Pull tool.
3. In the Header, in Drag, choose Tweak to activate the tool's gizmo.
4. In the Header, in Transform Pivot Point, choose Individual Origins.

[image]

---

Then just drag the gizmo. The vertices will move without deforming the scale.

[image]

Comment: Great solution :). Looks like Blender has a dedicated tool for everything...